# Windows Junction / Move File Issues

Tags: windows-7, robocopy, junction

I am working on a computer where I am moving `C:\Users\User` to `D:\Users\User` and I am going to create a [junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point). All files moved successfully during the move except:

1. My Pictures
2. My Videos
3. CurrentDatabase_372 (Windows Media Library)
4. rnupgagent.exe

*My Pictures* and My Videos were *shared* at the time of the move, so that is probably why they encountered an error needing permission from the admin user. I created another admin user to do this. I cannot complete the move even in Safe Mode and the `C:\Users\User` folder cannot be renamed to `C:\Users\User.old` to complete the junction.

I am using [this site](http://www.starkeith.net/coredump/2009/05/18/how-to-move-your-windows-user-profile-to-another-drive/), which referred me to this page for any questions.

At this point, about 20 files reside in the `C:\Users\User` directory, files like `NTUSER.dat`, and other registry named files.

I tried using RoboCopy GUI to complete the move too. RoboCopy GUI is greyed out for some reason. I don't want to reformat the drives.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: On Windows you cannot manipulate with open files. Start some other OS with your system disk attached as E: (or you may use the linux) to move those files...